# Setting a css class to HtmlInputCheckBox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, checkbox

I am creating an HtmlInputCheckBox in C# and I am trying to set a css for it, but I cannot. Can anyone give me a sample code? 
For example, the one below is not working.

```
HtmlInputCheckBox FieldCtrl = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
FieldCtrl.ID = "CheckBox1";
FieldCtrl.Style = "CheckBox";
```

Comment: In your example you've got the field defined as Field, and you are referencing it FieldCtrl. Is this a typo in the example or is it a problem in your code?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Typo fixed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.Net doesn't directly expose a lot of the normal HTML attributes, but you can access it through the Attributes collection.

```
FieldCtrl.Attributes["class"] = "MyCssClass";
```

Comment: Or:
            HtmlInputCheckBox FieldCtrl = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
            FieldCtrl.Attributes.Add("class", "className");